# using traditional javascript objects in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am trying my might at doing a NODE JS project, and learning the in's and outs of the Node JS structure. I have looked all over the internet to find out how to do this with little or no luck. The problem is as follows:

I have a class called player, which was created in a file called player.js

```
var playa = function ()
 {

       this.createPlayer = function(){

       }

 }
```

In my index.js file I link my player

```
      var playa = require("./player.js");
```

however, when I try to reference my player

```
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
       var player =   new playa();
        player.createPlayer();
});
```

the console tells me that playa is not a function and the server stops.

1. Am I even allowed to use traditional OOP JS in node? If I move this class to the index.js file it works splendidly, however it will get sloppy since the class is large and I plan on using at least 5 classes.

2.If it is possible too structure my objects this way, how do I link them/reference them correctly?

1. if neither or possible, what would be the correct way to structure my objects? I am hoping not to get away from my current convention since that is what I am used to and I need to create multiple instances of player.

Comment: I don't think you're properly exporting the symbol from your module.

Comment: Currently you do not export anything (or `undefined` as a default value) from your `player.js` module. Hence the error.

Comment: I tried using module export.. When I did cosnole told me I had a type error and playa was not a function @Sirko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you export the constructor as a *property* of `module.exports`, then you'll have to refer to it by that as a property of the value returned from `require()`:

```
var playa = require("./player.js");
var player = new playa.playa();
```

If you want `require()` to return the function itself, you can write

```
module.exports = function()
{
   this.createPlayer = function(){

   }
}
```

Comment: So first i have to reference the namespace ie the export than the underlying class. Jeez i feel sheepish,. Thank you @Pointy

Comment: @Dnaso think of it this way: the return value of `require()` is whatever the value of `module.exports` ended up being when the imported module runs. It starts off as a simple empty object, but you can make it be whatever you want - in this case, a function.

Comment: interesting. I kind of like the way Node makes you structure your scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the bottom of your player.js file

```
module.exports.playa = playa;
```

This will allow that "class" to be available

**EDIT**

You will need to create an instance like the following:

```
var p = require('./player.js')
var player = new p.playa();
```

Comment: var player =   new playa();
               ^
TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: that was the console output, followed by my server crashing

Comment: @tier1 Currently you have a mistake with upper/lower case letters for the function. You export as lowercase, but use as uppercase.